# Can't increase swap size: the swapfile appears to have holes

Tags: command-line, swap, 19.10, resize

Edit: I gave up to struggle with 19.10. Due to my research it has serious bugs especially with 5.3 kernel. Too much people have same issues and there is not only one solution that won't work for me. I will try 18 lts version.

I'm using Ubuntu 19.10 with 5.3.26 kernel and have 4 GB RAM but my swap size is 2 GB RAM. My system freezes nearly whole time. So, I decided to increase swap size but I have an error like that.

I used these commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=4
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
```

It's okay until the last part:

```
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

When I used the last command, it says:

```
swapon: /swapfile: skipping - it appears to have holes.
```

This is lsblk output

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda2   8:2    0    50M  0 part /boot/grub
├─sda3   8:3    0     2G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda4   8:4    0     2G  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0 114,7G  0 part
```

This is df output

```
Filesystem     Type     1M-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      vfat           511     8       504   2% /boot/efi
/dev/sda2      ext4            45     8        33  20% /boot/grub
udev           devtmpfs      1883     0      1883   0% /dev
udev           devtmpfs      1883     0      1883   0% /dev
udev           devtmpfs      1883     0      1883   0% /dev
```

Comment: Did you turn swap off first: $ sudo swapoff -a

Comment: yes I forgot to add I used swap off first.

Comment: That should mean something else changed something on the disk.

Comment: What file system are you using? This should work with ext4 (maybe unless the drive is almost full), but there may be problems with some other file system.

Comment: The output of `df` makes me surprised. I would expect a line for the root file system, a device mounted on **`/`**. Please check again and add more lines to the output of `df`, if you find such lines. You can also show us the whole output of `sudo lsblk -f`, which should show if there are file systems in `/dev/sda4` and `/dev/sda5` and in that case, what file systems.

Comment: With my older system with only 4GB of RAM, I never used swap. And increasing swap is probably not going to solve issue. What does this show: `free -l` And even if RAM use higher, it is just caching what you previously loaded, in case you load it again, or will release it if you load something new. You can check what is using system resources with `top` or instlal htop and use `htop`

Comment: Please post the full `lsblk` output (no `grep`). You seem to be using LVM and the filtering [suggested by Broadsworde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1205166/cant-increase-swap-size-the-swapfile-appears-to-have-holes#comment2022351_1205190) hides it. Also did you apply any filtering for your `df` command? You should mention the actual commands you ran when posting their output.

Comment: @Melebius My earlier comment got deleted, he ran: df -Tm /dev/sda1 /dev/sda2 /dev/sda3 /dev/sda4 /dev/sda5

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu Community** [SwapFAQ](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) shows use of `fallocate` as initial and quicker approach, only falling back on `dd` if `fallocate` fails.

**Example Given (1GiB)**:

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo fallocate -l 1g /mnt/1GiB.swap
$ sudo chmod 600 /mnt/1GiB.swap
$ sudo mkswap /mnt/1GiB.swap
Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 1048576 kB
$ sudo swapon /mnt/1GiB.swap
$ cat /proc/swaps 
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/home/swapfile                          file            1048576 1048576 -1
$ echo '/mnt/4GiB.swap swap swap defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
$ reboot
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        9.3G        454M        4.0G        5.8G        1.9G
Swap:          1.0G        0B          1.0G
```

**Your Case (4GiB)** - Using `fallocate`:

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo fallocate -l 4G /yourswapfile
$ sudo chmod 600 /yourswapfile
$ sudo mkswap /yourswapfile
$ sudo swapon /yourswapfile
$ echo '/yourswapfile swap swap defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
$ free -h
```

**Your Case (4GiB)** - Using `dd`:
**Note:** Same process you used except smaller `bs` value (read/write bytes at a time) to reduce possibility of holes in swapfile. I also added `status=progress` which shows periodic transfer statistics.

```
$ sudo swapoff -a
$ sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/yourswapfile bs=1M count=4096 status=progress
```

**Note:** If `bs=1M count=4096` is too slow, try `bs=4M count=1024`

Comment: It says fallocate: fallocate failed: Operation not supported when I tried to enter first fallocate command.

Comment: What filesystem are you using and how much free space available on the partition you're trying to create the swapfile on?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu for the first time. How can I check that? My swapfile is 2gb right now. I searched about increase they say if u have 4gb ram you should increase to 4gb so I decided to make it 4 gb.

Comment: Can you update (edit) your question to include output from: $ lsblk | egrep 'NAME|disk|part'

Comment: I updated with the output of that command.

Comment: @nogabemist, did you try the dd with smaller bs size? Version 20.04 LTS comes out in April

Answer (score 0):

The use of files for swap space is relatively new for Ubuntu.  Previously, when a swap partition was used, the blocks were of course contiguous, but a file has no such guarantee for its blocks.  Apparently, there was some effort to allow for gaps, but there may be limits on what can be handled. See the note at the end of the "man mkswap" manual page:

```
Note that a swap file must not contain any holes.  Using cp(1) to create the file is not acceptable.  Neither is  use  of
       fallocate(1)  on  file systems that support preallocated files, such as XFS or ext4, or on copy-on-write filesystems like
       btrfs.  It is recommended to use dd(1) and /dev/zero in these cases.  Please read notes from swapon(8)  before  adding  a
       swap file to copy-on-write filesystems.
```

The immediate fix is to simply reallocate some partition to dedicate 4G to a swap partition, and mkswap on it.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after default install with ZDF. 2G swap partition - and no more.
The solution I've found in this thread: [ZFS swap size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1197263/increase-zfs-swap-partition-size), and used it even w/o changing paths, just selected another size, 32G:

```
zfs create -V 8G -b $(getconf PAGESIZE) -o logbias=throughput -o sync=always -o primarycache=metadata -o com.sun:auto-snapshot=false rpool/swap
mkswap -f /dev/zvol/rpool/swap
swapon /dev/zvol/rpool/swap

# IN FSTAB (before the line with current swap file or partition)
/dev/zvol/rpool/swap none swap discard 0 0
```

Check if it worked for you: `free -m`

**But my new SSD was almost free, so no problem to allocate large continuous files.** Doing it on almost full drive after many create/append/shrink/remove file operations could be a problem for sure!!!